# Ошибка TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation при напсании бота

Tags: python, telebot

Делал бота на телеграм:

```
import telebot
import config
from telebot import types 
import random

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN, threaded=False)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    sti=open('stikers/hello_game.webp', 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)

    #keyboard
    markup=types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1=types.KeyboardButton("random cifra")
    item2=types.KeyboardButton("how are you?")

    markup.add(item1,item2)


    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"privetstvou tebya, {0.first_name}!\nYa - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, stupid bot ot tovarischa Fletla".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
        parse_mode='html',reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lolomg(message):
    if message.chat.type=='private':
        if message.text=='random cifra':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(random.randint(0,100)))
        elif message.text=='how are you?':

            markup=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            item1=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup("horosho",callback_data='good')
            item2=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup("ploho",callback_data='bad')

            markup.add(item1,item2)

            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'namana, sam kak?',perly_markup=markup)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ya ne znau kak tebe otvetit')



@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data=='good':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'vot i horosho')
            elif call.data=='bad':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'bivaet')
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text=" Как дела?",
                reply_markup=None)
            bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False,
                text="ты нажал")
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))


# RUN
#bot.polling(none_stop = True)
bot.infinity_polling(True)
```

выдает ошибку:

```
File "telegram.py", line 76
    print(repr(e))
                 ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

никак найти проблему не могу(и в гугле ничего не нашел)
(и да это бот по гайду от хауди, но даже его код не запускается)

Comment: Эта ошибка означает что где-то вы делаете отступы пробелами, где-то табуляцией..это неправильно, в питоне все надо пробелами делать.

Comment: В pycharm можно настроить отображение отступов, чтобы видеть где у вас они пробельные, а где нет

Comment: `и в гугле ничего не нашел` - в смысле не нашел? Как минимум первые три ссылки ровно по теме: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCZIk.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас отступы сделаны и с табуляцией, и с пробелом. Нажмите Ctrl + A и увидите. Преобразуйте отступы в пробел.